# Determine value of input which by JS value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I write my application with `HTML`, `JS` and `Angular.js`.

Here is the relvant HTML part:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0" ng-repeat="app in apparray track by $index">
     // some HTML code
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="typex" style="width: 66%" id="inputEmail3" required="" value=app[0] placeholder=app[0] disabled>
  // More HTML code
 </div>
```

Here is the JS file:

```
wdConfControllers.controller('MController',
    function($scope, $modal, $location, WdConfClient) {
  //some code
   $scope.apparray = []
   $scope.init = function () {
       for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
               $scope.apparray.push(["appt", "", "", "", ""]);
    }
 }
```

I want that my input would prints the value of the first argument in the specific `app`. In our case is `appt`. But it prints `app[0]`.

How I get to the first argument in app[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate non angular attributes yourself by `{{}}`:

`value="{{app[0]}}" placeholder="{{app[0]}}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to tie the input to a particular value, that is what `ngmodel` is for, which you have tied to `typex`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="app[0]" style="width: 66%" id="inputEmail3" required="" disabled>
```